# Why are my TextViews being moved around?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, textview, android-xml

I am trying to display a single list item after the user clicks on an item. However, I have noticed that the layout is messed up when there is too much text. Sometimes it's pushed half way, sometimes it's completely to the right side of the screen. I don't understand why this is happening. How can I resolve this issue? Please note I have the exact same layout in a popup dialog with no problems.

This is my XML code:

```html
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/add_spot_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:shrinkColumns="1"
        android:stretchColumns="1" >

        <TableRow
            android:layout_marginBottom="1sp"
            android:layout_marginTop="2sp" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/nameDetails"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:textSize="25sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </TableRow>

        <!-- separator -->

        <View
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

        <TableRow
            android:layout_marginBottom="2sp"
            android:layout_marginTop="2sp" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_marginLeft="5sp"
                android:text="@string/distance"
                 />

            <TextView android:id="@+id/distanceDetails" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_marginBottom="2sp"
            android:layout_marginTop="2sp" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_marginLeft="5sp"
                android:text="@string/address"
                 />

            <TextView android:id="@+id/addrDetails" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_marginBottom="2sp"
            android:layout_marginTop="2sp" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_marginLeft="5sp"
                android:text="@string/type"
               />

            <TextView android:id="@+id/typeDetails" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_marginBottom="2sp"
            android:layout_marginTop="2sp" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_marginLeft="5sp"
                android:text="@string/terrain" />

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" >

                <RatingBar
                    android:id="@+id/terrainDetails"
                    style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleSmall"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:isIndicator="true"
                    android:max="5"
                    android:numStars="5"
                    android:stepSize="1" />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow>

            <TextView
                android:layout_marginLeft="5sp"
                android:text="@string/difficulty" />

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" >

                <RatingBar
                    android:id="@+id/difficultyDetails"
                    style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleSmall"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:isIndicator="true"
                    android:max="5"
                    android:numStars="5"
                    android:stepSize="0.1" />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_marginBottom="2sp"
            android:layout_marginTop="2sp" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_marginLeft="5sp"
                android:text="@string/description" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/descDetails"
                android:gravity="top"
                android:lines="2"
                android:maxLines="2"
                android:scrollHorizontally="false" />
        </TableRow>

        <View
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />
    </TableLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Here are some screenshots to show you what I mean:

What it should be:

[image]

What it shouldn't be:

Pushed to the right side of the screen

[image]

Too much text in description. Goes off the screen

[image]

Pushed only half way.

[image]

Comment: I tried your layout but I could reproduce your problem. You could try set layout_weight=1 to your right views.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The size of a column in a `TableLayout` is given by its largest content.

The way you organized your layout, the title **nameDetails** is in the **first column**. 
You'll notice that, in the cases you don't like, the second column is neatly aligned with the end of your title.

To solve this, either move the title out of the table layout, or use the [`android:layout_span`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableRow.LayoutParams.html#attr_android%3alayout_span) attribute to span it on 2 columns

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is happening because you have your title `@+id/nameDetails` as the first row of the table.  It is including the length of this `<textview>` cell when it determines the size of the left hand side of the table.

Can you move that textview out of the tableview?

Comment: Ahhh how did I not see that